# Best way to deploy from dev to production?

Tags: magento-1.9, deploy, deployment

Currently using Magento 1 for my website and I needed to deploy a new "Build" onto my live server. For the past few months, I would zip the dev server files, FTP to live server. I would also export the SQL database and import them onto the production server.

With my most recent deployments, things get messy and I either end up needing to roll back the deployment or deal with what I have on the fly.

I'm trying to see if there is a better way of moving files from the dev server to Production.

I've looked into using a repository. While I have somewhat basic understanding of PHP, I'm not sure if using something like Git would benefit me. I've had to edit files before, but I mainly make my changes in the admin panel.

Any suggestions?